# Vim & Syntastic: Sorting Errors before Warnings in the location list

Tags: sorting, vim, syntastic

I've found that some warnings can be affected by the presence of a syntax error.

Remove the error and, hey presto, the warning disappears or changes.

So as to not waste time dealing with fake warnings, I want to deal with the errors first, meaning that they would need to appear first in vim's location list.

Syntastic can sort, but `:help syntastic-config-sort` says it's `by line number, then by type, then by column number`. The only other option is to display in the order displayed by the generating compiler/checker... which is not configurable.

I know that I could do something like:

```
let g:syntastic_ruby_checkers=['errors-only', 'warnings-and-errors']
```

but that would further slow down the already slow-ish checking process in the general case where there are warnings but no errors.

Any way to get errors before warnings?

Or a work-around?

For instance, is there any way to run `errors-only` if an error is detected in the `warnings-and-errors` checker?

Or is there a way to: `let g:syntastic_quiet_messages = { "level" : "warnings" }` only if the list is empty for `"level" : "errors"`?

Comment: This is not possible, and there is currently no plan to add such a feature.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know, anyhow... and for a great plugin overall.

Comment: To prevent rubocop lying if there are syntax errors, I address those first:

let g:syntastic_ruby_checkers=['mri', 'rubocop']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My work-around for fixing errors before warnings is to populate the location list with the errors first, followed by the warnings:

```
let g:syntastic_ruby_checkers=['mri', 'rubocop']
```

If I save after fixing errors, then any fake warnings disappear.